# Permission denied when copying files from OSX backup disc

Tags: permissions, 16.04, copy

I have OSX backup disk which I want to backup. I get permission denied many times when trying to copy files graphically, from OSX system components. 
Not all files get permission denied. However, they are so many that I have to select "skip all" such things. This may skip something important.

---

How can you backup OSX disc with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: How are you doing it ? If you are doing it with the file manager, perhaps it's necessary to do so as root - run it as `gksudo nautilus` from a terminal to get privileged access to all files.

Comment: You should have it already - just type `gksudo nautilus` in a terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JonasCz's answer but also have the package `hfsprogs` installed before trying to access OS X filesystem

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
gksudo nautilus
```